# tyHow to define a struct union accessible via subscript like an array? like in GLSL

Tags: c, arrays, struct, types, unions

a long time ago I must have seen GLSL vectors somewhere and now we have a college project involving OpenGL (2.4 they said actually, not 3.x nor 4.x). However they seem to be highly tied with glsl, and I’d like to have the same thing in raw C: `struct`s with `x`/`r`, `y`/`g`, `b` potentially also being `z`. I tried to do one definition for each `vec2`, `vec3`, `vec4`, internally using int (because OpenGL does have functions using int, not long int, and I’m saying myself fixed-point may be faster or simpler), with their `unsigned` counterpart (because the teacher said it’d be better to use positive values for readability, readability and better intuition of what’s happening, while using translations afterwards for centering, while I prefer to change coordinates arithmetically in such a way it can be adapted at compile-time). That makes a lot space so I defined it using macros, so at the end I will also include a macro-less example version so you can have an idea if that seems unreadable to you.

The main problem is I can’t pass these structures to functions taking an array/pointer as a parameter (so I did define a union member as `.ptr` for more straightforward casting), nor can I apparently use array subscripts on them. I think I recall having seen somewhere a way to define a `struct` or an union with an array in such a way the `struct` or `union` could be subscripted directly to access that array, but I can’t find it again… maybe it was some GNU extension but I’m not sure.

Although if there is no way, and I still want readability, I still have the option of defining my types just using basic arrays, and then `union dim { x, y, z }` and access like `my_vec[x]` for instance. But I’d like to know if I can also use for the same type `my_vec.x`. Here the code:

```
typedef unsigned int uint;
#define VEC_TYPEDEF(type, type_name, n)                        \
  typedef union type_name ## vec ## n ## _t                    \
  {                                                            \
    struct                                                     \
    {                                                          \
      type x;                                                  \
      type y;                                                  \
      VEC_THIRD(type, z)                                       \
      VEC_FORTH(type, w)                                       \
    };                                                         \
    struct                                                     \
    {                                                          \
      type s;                                                  \
      type t;                                                  \
      VEC_THIRD(type, p)                                       \
      VEC_FORTH(type, q)                                       \
    };                                                         \
    struct                                                     \
    {                                                          \
      type r;                                                  \
      type g;                                                  \
      VEC_THIRD(type, b)                                       \
      VEC_FORTH(type, a)                                       \
    };                                                         \
    type ptr[n];                                               \
  } type_name ## vec ## n
#define VEC_THIRD(type, var) type var;
#define VEC_FORTH(type, var) type var;
VEC_TYPEDEF(int,, 4);
VEC_TYPEDEF(uint, u, 4);

#undef VEC_FORTH
#define VEC_FORTH(type, var)
VEC_TYPEDEF(int,, 3);
VEC_TYPEDEF(uint, u, 3);

#undef VEC_THIRD
#define VEC_THIRD(type, var)
VEC_TYPEDEF(int,, 2);
VEC_TYPEDEF(uint, u, 2);
```

One example of what it gives:

```
typedef union uvec3_t
{
  struct
  {
    unsigned int x;
    unsigned int y;
    unsigned int z;
  };
  struct
  {
    unsigned int s;
    unsigned int t;
    unsigned int p;
  };
  struct
  {
    unsigned int r;
    unsigned int g;
    unsigned int b;
  };
  unsigned int ptr[3];
} uvec3;
```

Currently if trying to use something like `my_vect.x = my_other_vect[0];` (with `uvec3 my_vect, my_other_vect;`), gcc will just bark out “error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector” :/

Comment: What you are trying to do is the direct opposite of readability. Don't use any unions or macros. Don't use structs to represent vectors, that's what arrays are for.

Comment: so my way with enum is just better in all terms? because I thought being able to use .x, .y and .z could improve readability (that’s what glsl do, and I did see that once)

Comment: dont you want to name your structs so you can get them in the enum?

Comment: .x. y. z do nearly nothing for readability, especially when (1) you read most of your coordinate data from files as you should, and (2) when you can choose an arbitrary coordinate system and switch freely between different systems. For those rare cases when you do really want xyz, `my_vec[x]` is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @GradyPlayer: No I don’t, my anonymous structs already do what I want (`uvec2 my_vec; […] my_vec.y […]`), I’d like an anonymous array as well actually.

Comment: @n.m.: okay you’re confirming my initial doubt. yet (1) doesn’t apply in my case because I’m not doing any serious or useful project but just a college homework that’s directly a raw game in opengl, rather than including any 3d engine features: so we build our stuff directly is code, as we shouldn’t ;)

Comment: I think you can try GLM but do not know if it can be used in C. I did exactly the same stuff in C++ for the same reasons to run GLSL code on CPU side too (I am not sure this can be done in C) as I ended up using templates and classes a lot (not usable in C)  ended up with script that write large part of the code for me as only vectors are ~228 KByte of code. Without templates it would be at least 4 times as much. And without class getters setters I do not even try to estimate. see RC QA with [vec2 and the script](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/6055/6868) C++ example

Comment: after that the actual type is defined like this `typedef _vec2<float >  vec2; typedef _vec3<float >  vec3; typedef _vec4<float >  vec4;` but I do not think you can port this into C but I might be wrong as I do not code in C ... There is also possibility to write C++ and compile as OBJ which would you link into your C. btw the script is very similar to the ND hypercube generator I answered you with as it generate all the combinations of getter/setter  like `x,y,z; xy,z; x,yz; ...` there are a lot of them for 3D,4D ...

Answer (score 0):

To do that first you need to make the struct packed so that there is no padding 
and then you can use it like this

```
* (<TYPE> *) ((void *)my_other_vect + sizeof(<TYPE>)*offset);
```

For example
for type of int and get x you can do this

```
my_vect.x = * (int *) ((void *)my_other_vect + sizeof(int)*0);
my_vect.y = * (int *) ((void *)my_other_vect + sizeof(int)*1);
```

Comment: What I asked was more about readability, syntax, types and how to avoid casting than this. Also, it may be non-standard and work only by chance, but currently my array ptr and my structs always have the exact same value, so no packing is currently needed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if this is what you are asking... but if you name your structs you can access them in your enum...

```
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned int x;
        unsigned int y;
        unsigned int z;
    }xyz_type;
    struct
    {
        unsigned int s;
        unsigned int t;
        unsigned int p;
    }stp_type;
    struct
    {
        unsigned int r;
        unsigned int g;
        unsigned int b;
    }rgb_type;
    unsigned int ptr[3];
} uvec3;


int main(void)
{
    uvec3 example;
    example.xyz_type.x = 1;
    example.stp_type.t = 2;
    example.rgb_type.b = 3;
    printf(" %u, %u, %u \n", example.ptr[0],example.ptr[1],example.ptr[2]);

}
```

also removed your _t enum tag... as you weren't using it... and all type names that end in _t are reserved by POSIX and you shouldn't use them.

Comment: ah okay, I took the `_t` by exactly copying glsl suggestion of implementation of their vectors, to name the enum. Didn’t know it was reserved. And no this isn’t at all what I do want, I want the direct opposite: not having anymore to specify “.ptr”, not having to specify structs name.

Comment: @gelex-713... maybe you just want to use naked ptr[3] and define `r` to be 0... then use `ptr[r] = someval;`

Comment: yeah nearer to that, as discussed in question’s comments.